# How can I load weather data into BigQuery

Tags: dataset, google-bigquery, weather, opendata

I want to load weather data into BigQuery. I'm looking forward into correlating weather patterns against my own datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I have this script to download NOAAs worldwide daily gsod data into BigQuery:

```
#!/bin/bash
year=$1
# Folder for each year.
mkdir -p $year
# Get yearly data from NOAA.
wget ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/gsod/$year/gsod_$year.tar -O $year/gsod_$year.tar
# Untar one file per day.
tar -xvf $year/gsod_$year.tar -C $year/
# Archive not needed anymore.
rm $year/gsod_$year.tar
# Unzip each file.
find $year -name "*.gz" -print0 | xargs -0 gunzip
# Merge all files.
find $year -name "*.op" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -h -v STN  > $year.op
# Transform NOAA's format to csv.
# in2csv from https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/
# gsod_schema.csv from https://github.com/tothebeat/noaa-gsod-data-munging/
in2csv -s gsod_schema.csv $year.op > $year.csv
# Load into BigQuery.
bq load --max_bad_records 10 --replace weather_gsod.gsod$year $year.csv stn,wban,year,mo,da,temp:float,count_temp:integer,dewp:float,count_dewp:integer,slp:float,count_slp:integer,stp:float,count_stp:integer,visib:float,count_visib:integer,wdsp,count_wdsp,mxpsd,gust:float,max:float,flag_max,min:float,flag_min,prcp:float,flag_prcp,sndp:float,fog,rain_drizzle,snow_ice_pellets,hail,thunder,tornado_funnel_cloud
```

It downloads the yearly NOAA archives, unpacks, uncompresses each file, and then transforms the special NOAA encoding into CSV readable by BigQuery.

- Some example queries at [/r/bigquery/.../noaa_gsod_weather_data_loaded_into_bigquery/](http://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/2ts9wo/noaa_gsod_weather_data_loaded_into_bigquery/).
- Find the shared data at [/table/fh-bigquery:weather_gsod.gsod2014](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:weather_gsod.gsod2014).